# vb.net ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub CalculateB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateB.Click
    '//////////Configuration/////////////////////////////////////////


    Dim lb As Integer = 1
    Dim ub As Integer = 3

    Dim fname As String = "D:\Onechrmsm.txt"
    Dim chrmsmize As Integer = 18
    '///////////////////fin confoguration////////////////////////////
    Dim cgen As New Chrmsm

    cgen = RandomGen(chrmsmize, lb, ub)
    'cgen.Genome = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

    cgen = Solve({cgen}.ToList)(1)

    WriteTextToFile({cgen.Bfitness, cgen.Bfitness, "solution", StringGenerator(cgen.Solution), "PMPlan", StringGenerator(cgen.Genome)}, fname, True)
    MsgBox(cgen.Fitness)

End Sub

Public Function Solve(ByRef population As List(Of Chrmsm), Optional ByVal PMBt As Double = 1111) As List(Of Chrmsm)
    Dim newPop As New List(Of Chrmsm)
    '==============================================================
    Dim nbT As Integer = 6
    Dim nbM As Integer = 3
    Dim nbP As Integer = 2
    'Dim PMBt As Double = 1111
    Dim penalty As Double = 111
    Dim fname As String = "D:\results.txt"

    '=============================================================
    Dim PMB As Array = {PMBt, PMBt, PMBt, PMBt, PMBt, PMBt}

    For i As Integer = 1 To population.Count - 1
        Dim cchrmsm As New Chrmsm
        cchrmsm = population(i)
        If Not cchrmsm.IsSolved Then
            cchrmsm = solveM(cchrmsm, nbT, nbM, nbP, PMB, penalty, fname, False)
        End If
        newPop.Add(cchrmsm)
    Next
    Return newPop
End Function
Public Structure Chrmsm
    Public Property Bfitness As Double
    Public Property DetailSolution As Double()
    Public Property Distance As Double
    Public Property Entropy As Double
    Public Property Fitness As Double
    Public Property Genome As Integer()
    Public Property IsFeasible As Boolean
    Public Property IsSolved As Boolean
    Public Property Rank1 As Integer
    Public Property Rank2 As Integer
    Public Property Solution As Double()
End Structure
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Four space indent to format your code here.

Comment: Must also add `RandomGen` and `solveM` definitions

Comment: Please check the screen shot to get the problem I faced.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help asking a proper question.

Comment: You might also be interested to know that arrays and lists start at `0`, and not `1`.

Comment: I test both 0 and 1 and i got the same error every time

Comment: So it seems then that no items have been added to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim cgen As New Chrmsm
```

Gives you a new instance of the Chrmsm structure

```
cgen = RandomGen(chrmsmize, lb, ub)
```

I am assuming that RandomGen returns an instance of Chrmsm Which means you wasted your New instance. Just...

```
Dim cgen As Chrmsm = RandomGen(chrmsmize, lb, ub)
```

I broke the next line up so I could better understand it.

```
Dim lstChrsms1 As List(Of Chrmsm) = {cgen}.ToList
```

Created a list on one Chrmsm at index 0.
Regarding the following line of code...

```
cgen = Solve({cgen}.ToList)(1)
```

Your Solve function returns a List(Of Chrmsm) so cannot be assigned to a variable of type Chrmsm.
So...

```
Dim lstChrsms2 as List(OfChrism) = Solve(lstChrsms1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't `Solve({cgen}.ToList)(1)` access index 1 in the list returned by `Solve`?  That should be assignable to a variable of type `Chrmsm`.